# Stop/Abort PowerExchange Logger Service

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I'm getting following errors while trying to stop the PWX logger:

**Could not exectute action...
[DOM_10213] Internal error. Could not update the service state in the domain configuration repository because of the following errors:
[RSVCSHARED_00018] Internal error. The request processing failed for the following reason:
['Exception Class[Class javax.persistence.persistenceException] Exception message [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: cannot open connection]']**

I Tried both complete and Abort option but same issue persists . 
Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
Actually the password for the informatica user had been expired. I alter the user with the same old password and its working fine.